# Read only the float in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with file handling exercise.
So my txt file have this content:

```
List of Sales
Day 1 : 1250.25
Day 2 : 2560.25
Day 3 : 3241.10
Day 4 : 1530.20
Day 5 : 1247.27
Day 6 : 1646.22
Day 7 : 850.25
```

I want to only get the amount per day and sum it.

```
OFile = open('sales.txt','r')
file_content = OFile.read()
print(file_content)

import re
get = re.findall(r'[.]', file_content)
amount = []
for n in range(7):
    amount.append(get)
total = sum(amount)
print("Total sales Amount: ", "Php", total)
```

I keep getting Total sales Amount 0

Comment: why you are using regex when you can use `strip` and `split` to do the work ?

Comment: `get` is a list of strings. You append it 7 times to `amount` so that is a list of lists of strings. Then you call `sum` on `amount`. I don't see how that is supposed to work, but I'd expect it to raise an exception. How can it be giving you zero?

Comment: When running your example, I get TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Comment: My bad, didn't update it, I did also get the TypeError

Answer (score -1):

keep it simple and use `str.split` and `str.strip` instead of using regex!
In your case (with the input file you have attached)
Exception may raised from the conversion to float (if you have
invalid line or some string that can not be converted to float!
Or line that have no **":"** (e.g. the first line in the file) which causes
the split() call to return the same input string as a list of one string (the line)
without spaces.In both cases you want to
skip and continue to next line!

```
total_sum = 0

with open('sales.txt','r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        try:
            current_float_num = line.strip().split(":")[1]
            current_float_num = float(current_float_num)
            # do work on float_num
            # for example add it to the accumulative total_sum
            total_sum += current_float_num
        except (IndexError,ValueError):
            continue
```

Comment: This will throw an error because the first line in the text file does not contain a colon

Comment: A `try except` like thisis very dangerous because if one line is wrong, it'll still return an (incorrect) result. Instead skip the header and read the rest.

Comment: @mahdilamb - i saw your edit. i reject it, because in python and in any OOP language we do our best to prevent using the if else old school programming. rather than asking for each line (`if ":" in line`) i am using the try except block. using if else for each line is nonpythonic and reduce the performance of the code especialy when we have only one line (first line in the file) that violates the `split(":")` expression. using try except is more pythonic and do not harm or reduce the code performance.

Comment: @Nathan - you are assuming that the last token in each line is number! maybe it is not a number and the conversion to float can then raise ValueError exception! your comment is unclear to me since if one line is inccorect then the conversion to float will raise exception! and in this case i am continuing to the next line! so this is the right logic to do in such case.

Comment: Thanks, solved it instead of using regex, i used strip and split. thanks for @Adam

Comment: You're worried about "performance"?  If the last token is not a number it SHOULD raise an exception. @adam

Comment: @Nathan it did raise an exception. AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper'

Comment: @Nathan- OK. so what is wrong in my answer? this exception will end up (will be swallowed) in the except block! by the way i cant see the line in the sales.txt file that raises this exception (`AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper'`).